# How to implement Percy in TestCafe

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) and trying to integrate Percy for visual regression tests. I've already imported [Percy SDK](https://docs.percy.io/docs/build-your-own-sdk#section-using-percy-agent-as-a-library-in-your-code) but I get this error `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`. Any insight on how to implement this would be helpful.

```
const PercyAgent = require('@percy/agent').default;
export default class Helper {
  takeSnapshot(snapshotName: any, snapshotOptions: any) {
    const percyAgentClient = new PercyAgent({
      clientInfo: 'awesome-percy-sdk@0.0.1',
      environmentInfo: 'some helpful os or browser information for debugging',
    });
    percyAgentClient.snapshot(snapshotName, snapshotOptions);
  }
}
```

```
test('Regression | Login with wrong credentials | 102', async (t) => {
  loginPage.login('not_existent@xpta.com', 'RandomPassword1');
  await t.expect(loginPage.errorMessage.visible).ok();
  await t.debug();
  await t.expect(loginPage.errorMessage.innerText).eql('Invalid username or password.');
  await helper.takeSnapshot('wrong credentials', {});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Percy agent client is running in the TestCafe node process instead of running in the browser. This is why you get an error.

You should, in a first step, inject the Percy client in the browser by following this documentation: [Injecting External Libraries into a Page from a Test](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/examples-of-using-client-functions.html#injecting-external-libraries-into-a-page-from-a-test)

In a second step, you should convert the Helper class into a `Client Function` as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the this [official package (@percy/testcafe)](https://github.com/percy/percy-testcafe) to use Percy in combination with TestCafe.

After importing the library, taking snapshots through Percy within your e2e-tests with TestCafe is pretty straight forward:

```
import percySnapshot from '@percy/testcafe';

fixture('MyFixture')
  .page('http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');

test('Test1', async t => {
  await t.typeText('#developer-name', 'John Doe');
  await percySnapshot(t, 'TestCafe Example');
});
```

Remember to set your project specific Percy Token before running the tests, so that Percy can create a new Build each time your tests are run.

To set the token on Mac OS:

```
export PERCY_TOKEN=[your-project-token]
```

To set the token on Windows:

```
set PERCY_TOKEN=[your-project-token]
```

You can add a new script to your package.json to simplify making a test run:

```
"scripts": {
    "percy:chrome": "percy exec -- testcafe chrome src/testcafe/tests"
  },
```

Additionally, you can also use [this tutorial](https://docs.percy.io/docs/testcafe-tutorial) as an orientation to get you set up.